# How to fade in changed text with CSS psuedo element

Tags: css

I have a button that changes the text on hover. It's created by using the CSS content property and pseudo elements, but when I hover over the text it abruptly changes. Instead, I want the old text to fade into the new one.

Edit: Here is my code.

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #03a9f4;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  margin: 40px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#launchtrailerbtn:before {
  content: "LAUNCH TRAILER";
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

#launchtrailerbtn:hover:after {
  content: "CLICK TO VIEW TRAILER";
}

#launchtrailerbtn:hover:before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  content: "\f04b";
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a id="launchtrailerbtn" class="btn btn-primary"></a>
```

Since the new text is longer I also want the background of the button to slowly stretch into the new length.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: please add your code. thanks

Comment: @XenioGracias I added it in an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really help you much without specific code. But using `opacity` and `transition` is an example of what you can do to make text 'fade'.

```css
div {
  background: pink;
  padding: 5px 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  width: max-content;
}

div::after {
  content: 'I faded!';
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}

div:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I added my code in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

used `opacity` to show and hide with transition. hope it helps you. thanks

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #03a9f4;
  padding: 12px 18px;
  margin: 40px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#launchtrailerbtn:before {
  content: "LAUNCH TRAILER";
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
 opacity:1
}

#launchtrailerbtn:after {
  content: "CLICK TO VIEW TRAILER";
   transition: all 1s ease;
  opacity:0;
  margin-left: -186px;
}

#launchtrailerbtn:hover:after{
opacity:1;
transition: all 1s ease;
}

#launchtrailerbtn:hover:before{
opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<a id="launchtrailerbtn" class="btn btn-primary"></a>
```

Comment: The fading works great, thanks. But I still want the button to scale in width to fit the content. Can you help with that as well? Edit: Is there also a way to not use the margin-left? It breaks the responsiveness of the site.